# Ruby on Rails using different footer styling in each page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a footer div in application.html.erb file. Footer position is relative, but for few pages, I want to set footer position as fixed. How can I do that, without adding footer code on each page?

Comment: do you have rules? e.g. for page1, page2, page3  it will be relative, the rest will be fixed?

Comment: you can create different Layouts for each page

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Could you give me more information about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and nasty way might be,

Creating a partial (probably you've already done)

**pages/_footer.html.erb**

```
<div class='footer <%= @position||"relative" %>'>
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Adding a private method to controller(s).

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :foo, :destroy]
  before_action :fixed_footer, only: [:show, :edit, :mission, :vision]

  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def foo
    render 'show'
  end

  def about
    render 'some_static_page'
  end

  def mission
    render 'some_static_page' 
  end

  def vision
    render 'some_static_page' 
  end

  .....

  private
    def fixed_footer
      @position = "fixed"
    end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_page
      @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:title, :email, :comments)
    end
end
```

Then referencing to it in your layout file (as I've quickly created and scaffolded, I've only application layout).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simpleapp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'pages/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's all. Actually not all, What you've to do is, to give some style to `fixed` and `relative` classes in your stylesheet file.

Results: [index, show, new, foo, edit]. 2 and 5 has fixed class.

```
$ curl http://lvh.me:3000/pages | grep "div class='footer"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2815    0  2815    0     0  18599      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18642
    <div class='footer relative'>
$ curl http://lvh.me:3000/pages/1 | grep "div class='footer"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2388    0  2388    0     0  16032      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16135
    <div class='footer fixed'>
$ curl http://lvh.me:3000/pages/new | grep "div class='footer"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2833    0  2833    0     0  12242      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12264
    <div class='footer relative'>
$ curl http://lvh.me:3000/pages/1/foo | grep "div class='footer"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2391    0  2391    0     0  16165      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16265
    <div class='footer relative'>
$ curl http://lvh.me:3000/pages/1/edit | grep "div class='footer"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2959    0  2959    0     0  19393      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19467
    <div class='footer fixed'>
```

Comment: But if wanna to set fixed position for static pages? Could you help with that?

Comment: It's same. I've updated my answer do demonstrate how it will become possible. Just do not forget to update routes file. 

p.s. @max already posted a good and more rails-way answer. you should use that and thank him -))

Answer (score 2):

You can add classes to the `<body>` or `<html>` element:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # takes an array or list of strings and makes a string suited
  # for a html class attribute.
  # @param [String*|Array] args
  # @return [String]
  def css_class(*args)
    [*args].flatten.compact.join(" ") 
  end
end
```

---

```
<body class="<%=  css_class(controller_name, action_name) %>">
```

This will let you attach styles to a certain controller or action:

```
.users #footer {
  height: 100px;
}

.users.show #footer {
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I would not say that the is the Rails way of doing it - its just a pattern I adapted from doing wordpress themes and use sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture).

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def footer_tag(**kwargs)
    klass = "some-default-class " + (content_for(:footer_class) || ""
    content_tag(:footer, kwargs.merge(class: klass)) do
      yeild if block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/views/shared/_footer.html.erb
<% footer_tag do %>
  <p>Copyright 2017, EvilCorp</p>
<% end %>
```

And you would then use `provide` or `content_for` in your views:

```
<% content_for(:footer_class, "fixed") %>
<% provide(:footer_class, "fixed") %>
```

The difference being that the first concats to the buffer while the later flushes straight to the layout and marks the yield as finished.

Answer (score 1):

In `application.html.erb` you can access the `<body>` opening tag and change it into something like this `<body class="<%= params[:controller] %>-<%= params[:action] %>">`

Then if you have for example a restaurant application, you'll have a restaurants controller with maybe an `index` and a `show`.

Now on these pages the body will have a class called `.restaurants-index` and `.restaurants-show`

If you're using SCSS you can then say

```
.restaurants-index {
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
  }
}

.restaurants-show {
  .navbar {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I see my answer is a duplicate.